# Require & Memory Consumption

Tags: android, ios, react-native, memory-management

How does `require("path/to/image")` work?

For something like this:

```
export const images = {
   image1: require("path/to/image-1"),
   image2: require("path/to/image-2"),
   ...
};

<Image source={images.image1} />
```

When does the I/O operation to load the image happen? The moment it is declared in the `require` or when it is assigned to the `Image` component?

With I/O I mean also reading bytes from the image file available on the disk. I was trying to understand the consequence of doing `<Image source={require("path/to/image-1")} />` vs. `<Image source={images.image1} />`. I wonder if the I/O (disk read) is already happening the moment the application starts i.e. even before the images are used in a specific screen.

Answer (score 1):

The actual pulling of the file happen when you import the file containing the definition of `images`. This is the time when the I/O happen. But that's how it works on the server (if you are server-side rendering this component). If you are doing this on the client `path/to/image-1` and `path/to/image-2` are probably already in your bundled JavaScript file so there is no *I/O* operation (or a http request).

P.S.
The picture looks differently if you use dynamic imports but as far as I can see that's not the case.

P.S.S.
Actually now when I see that you tagged your question with react-native I have to say that the things may look different there.

Comment: With I/O I mean also reading bytes from the image file available on the disk. I was trying to understand the consequence of doing `<Image source={require("path/to/image-1")} />` vs. `<Image source={images.image1} />` (i.e: what I mentioned above). I wonder if the I/O (disk read) is already happening the moment the application starts even before the images are used in a specific screen.

Comment: If you require the file and that `images` declaration is at the top of the file yes it gets read. If your require is in a render function of a component I guess not yet (but that will be weird).